# Embed Tag not working

Tags: javascript

Guys i know stack overflow is not for debugging but i have my final high school examinations tomorrow and i am desperate, please dont downvote me. I have been trying to run this code for so long and now i am almost at verge of tears. Please do help. I am trying to embed a youtube video in my webpage and i have no idea what i am doing wrong, please rectify my code. Thanks a lot.

```
<html>
<body>
  <script language = "javascript">
    <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344">
    </embed>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this wrapped in a `script` element, and why are you trying to use `embed`, instead of the `iframe` the code generator on the youtube site already created for you?

Comment: My teacher asked me to use embed tag, i have no idea i just started coding few months back and Coding teachers suck in India, please do help

Comment: Well then remove the nonsense `script` element, and it’ll work, even with embed: https://jsfiddle.net/cv1hwoxu/

Comment: You my dear friend, are a god among men , Salute !!! Type out ur answer i will mark it correct. Thank You so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wrapped the `embed` into a `script` element. Remove the `script` element wrapper, and it will work:

```html
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344">
</embed>
```

Doesn’t work embedded as a code snippet here, but that has different reasons. https://jsfiddle.net/cv1hwoxu/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344">
</body>
</html>
```

This should work, for more info on the tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot, Help appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script language = "javascript">
</script>
<embed width="425" height="344" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g">
</body>
</html>
```

this will work. It was not working because you included it in script

Comment: Thank You, You were a lot of help !!!

Comment: No problem , Thats what we are here for, To help out people in need :)

Comment: Marking answers as correct will help people like us contribute more towards questions like these